# Shell script to check a log file and print the errors that are found in it

Tags: oracle, shell

I am pretty new to shell scripting . I am trying to write a script to check for logfile for errors (error strings are hardcoded), and i have to print the lines containing the error . i am able to write the logic but need pointers to read a file from user input.

Appreciate the help thanks.

---

#### Logic:

1. Accept the logfile patch from user
2. Check if the logfile is present or not
3. If present search the file for lines containing the error string (eg. Error, ORA)
4. Print the lines containing error strings , also write the output to a logfile

---

Read the log file from user

Set error strings

```
search="ERROR"
```

set a path for output file

```
outfile="file1.txt"
```

---

#### Execution logic

```
find "$mydir" -type f -name "$filename" |while read file
  do
    RESULT=$(grep "$search" "$file")
      if [[ ! -z $RESULT ]]
         then
            echo "Error(s) in $file: $RESULT" >> "$outfile"
     fi
  done
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with "need pointers to read a file from user input". I assume "pointers" are script arguments.

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
expected=outfile
for f in $@
do
  if [ "$expected" = outfile ]; then
      OUTFILE=$1
      expected=search
  elif [ "$expected" = search ]; then
      SEARCH=$2
      expected=files
  elif [[ -f $f ]]; then
      RESULT=`grep "$SEARCH" $f`
      if [ -n "$RESULT" ]; then
           echo -e "\n"
           echo "Error(s) in "$f":"
           echo $RESULT
           echo -e "\n" >> $OUTFILE
           echo "Error(s) in "$f":" >> $OUTFILE
           echo $RESULT >> $OUTFILE
      fi
  fi
done
```

Invoke with:

```
scriptname outfile search files
```

where:

- scriptname: is the name of file containing the script.
- outfile: the name of the output file
- search: the text to be searched
- files: one or many file name or file patterns.

Examples (I assume the name of the script is searcherror and it is in the system path):

```
searcherror errorsfound.txt primary /var/log/*.log

searcherror moreerrors.txt "ORA-06502" file1.log /var/log/*.log ./mylogs/*
```